# Export my block configuration

Tags: blocks

I have used configuration management to export and import my drupal configurations.However,when i add a new block,the configuration management can't track the change of block and i can't export the configuration.I want to know whether the configuration management can track the block and export block configuration.

Comment: Are you using this module? https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration? I suggest you edit your question a bit to make it more clear what     module you are using.

Comment: Yes,i'm using this module but it can't export block configuration.

Answer (score 1):

[Configuration Management](https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration) module  does not support exporting blocks. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2125089 for more info.

There are several other modules than can help you with this:

- [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) and [Features Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/features_extra)
- [Blockexport](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockexport)

Comment: Thanks.And does it has a better way to export configuration of a website (including content type and block configuration)

Comment: Just experiment with features module and use https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm for exporting settings. It will cover most of the things you will want to export.